# How to add application footer (Using bottomNavigationBar)

Tags: flutter

We can add a header using AppBar widget.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        leading: new Icon(Icons.mail),
        title: new Text("Hello Flutter Header"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new MyButton(),
      ),
      // **************************************
      // I want to add application footer here
      // **************************************
    );
  }
}
```

How can we add an Application Footer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Sticky Site Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120195/creating-a-sticky-site-footer)

Answer (score 4):

There is a [`persistentFooterButtons`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/persistentFooterButtons.html) property in `Scaffold`.

Answer (score 1):

`persistentFooterButtons` will render above `bottomNavigationBar`. Here is my solution in 2021, to add the application footer using `bottomNavigationBar`.

Note, `title:` is deprecated you should be using `label:`

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Container(),
    bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
      items: [
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
          label: "Like",
        ),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_down),
          label: "Dislike",
        ),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.comment),
          label: "Comment",
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [bottomNavigationBar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) is working for me.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        leading: new Icon(Icons.mail),
        title: new Text("Hello Flutter Header"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new MyButton(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
            title: new Text("Add"),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.edit),
            title: new Text("Edit"),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.delete),
            title: new Text("Delete"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As mentioned by @aziza, we can use persistentFooterButtons also. But in this approach buttons are not spaning perfectly in the horizontal direction.

```
 persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: null,
        ),
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.edit),
          onPressed: null,
        ),
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.delete),
          onPressed: null,
        ),
      ],
```

Another thing is both **bottomNavigationBar** and **persistentFooterButtons** can be used simultanously. **persistentFooterButtons** displyed between **body** and **bottomNavigationBar**.

Answer (score 0):

you can also accomplish that with [flutter_layouts](https://github.com/softmarshmallow/flutter-layouts)

https://github.com/softmarshmallow/flutter-layouts
https://github.com/softmarshmallow/flutter-layouts/tree/master/lib/src/footer

[image]