# Transparent sticky footer in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I was [following this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120195/creating-a-sticky-site-footer) for making a sticky footer. The footer performs like it needs to, but is there a way to add transparency so the items in the list behind the footer can be visible?

Solid footer
[image]

Transparent footer

[image]

Here is all the code for making the solid footer

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 200,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("title $index"),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            height: 40.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Stack` to display widgets on the top of each others.

```
new Scaffold(
  body: new Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    children: [
      new ListView(...),
      new Container(height: 40.0, color: Colors.red),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just tried it and the footer will now overlap with the last item (set using `itemCount: 200`) [https://i.imgur.com/oRpy3AC.png](https://i.imgur.com/oRpy3AC.png). To fix that, do you think measuring the height of the `Container` (because I want the `Container` height to be dynamic based on the text inside) then just adding that as extra padding is the best fix in Flutter?

Comment: Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: Hard to explain without a picture, but I don't want the container to cover up the last list item. So you just have to scroll to ListView height + `40` so the whole list can still be scrolled.