# How to implement position: sticky and bottom 0 with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to build a list view with sticky footer like [this article](https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46)'s "Stick to the bottom?!" in Flutter.

[image]

In CSS,

```
.main-footer{     
     position: sticky; 
     bottom: 0;
}
```

but how to do with Flutter?

## What I want

1. Scrollable large content
2. Footer (sticky)
3. Scrollable large content

1 and 2 are visible at First (Scrollable content and fixed footer). After scroll to end of 1, Footer (2) become not fixed. Rest of contents (3) will be shown below footer(2).

I tried to implement above with [CustomScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) but footer button is not drawn above list.

[image]

### code

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fixed footer',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _FixedFooterDemo(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _FixedFooterDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const _FixedFooterDemo({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Text('Fixed footer'),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(List.generate(20, _buildListItem)),
        ),
        SliverStickyFooter(
          child: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Fixed under list button'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('below space'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  ListTile _buildListItem(int i) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        'Item $i',
      ),
      subtitle: Text(
        'Sit est ipsum consequat sit ex. Minim magna laborum dolore aliqua sit dolore velit sint fugiat. Culpa officia tempor proident minim aliquip nisi reprehenderit ullamco duis mollit. Aute velit irure ut Lorem pariatur anim mollit cillum dolor irure quis. Eu officia dolore deserunt do est cupidatat duis elit. Pariatur magna reprehenderit aliquip ea irure Lorem sunt aute.',
        maxLines: 2,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SliverStickyFooter extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const SliverStickyFooter({
    Key key,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderSliverStickyFooter createRenderObject(BuildContext context) =>
      RenderSliverStickyFooter();
}

class RenderSliverStickyFooter extends RenderSliverSingleBoxAdapter {
  /// Creates a [RenderSliver] that wraps a [RenderBox] which is sized to fit
  /// the remaining space in the viewport.
  RenderSliverStickyFooter({
    RenderBox child,
  }) : super(child: child);

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    child?.layout(
      constraints.asBoxConstraints(),
      parentUsesSize: true,
    );

    final paintedChildSize =
        calculatePaintOffset(constraints, from: 0.0, to: child.size.height);
    assert(paintedChildSize.isFinite);
    assert(paintedChildSize >= 0.0);
    geometry = SliverGeometry(
      scrollExtent: child.size.height,
      paintExtent: paintedChildSize,
      maxPaintExtent: paintedChildSize,
      hasVisualOverflow: true,
      paintOrigin: -child.size.height + paintedChildSize,
      visible: true,
    );

    if (child != null) {
      setChildParentData(child, constraints, geometry);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm currently facing the same problem (footer button is not drawn above list). Did you manage to get any solution?
It seems that none of the answers below solve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Sticky extends StatefulWidget {
  Sticky({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _StickyState createState() => _StickyState();
}

class _StickyState extends State<Sticky> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black38,
                height: 60,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Text('Header'),
              ),
              top: 0,
            ),
            Positioned(
              child: Container(
                child: Text('Content'),
              ),
              top: 60,
            ),
            Positioned(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black38,
                height: 60,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Text('Footer'),
              ),
              bottom: 0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want footer to be "sticky". Footer is positioned at bottom first but after scrolling body footer will follow by content.

Answer (score 2):

What about having a Stack() with a ListView and then placing a Column with a Container placed at the bottom? It might isn't the answer you expect, but it works the way it's expected to. I tried thit:

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 30,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            child: Text(
                "Text\n"),
          );
        },
      ),
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 60,
            child: Text("That's the footer"),
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Column with three children, Header and Footer have a specific size and ListView occupies the remaining space.

```
        Column(
                children:[
                  Container(height: 100, child: HeaderWidget),
                  Expanded(child: ListView.builder(...)),
                  Container(height: 100, child: FooterWidget),
                ]
              ),
```

A scroll will be applied to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package

https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_infinite_list

In description there is a link to example app where you can play around with it.

This package supports sticky headers with top and bottom positioning also as left and right for both. It overlays content by default, but you can add margin to the bottom of your content, to prevent overlay and when header reaches it's min offset position

Answer (score 0):

The solution is built-in Flutter component - bottomNavigationBar:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: OverflowBar(
            overflowAlignment: OverflowBarAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              Text('Test')
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Note: It should be inside Scaffold, bottomNavigationBar is one component of the Flutter Scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

You already have existing solution in scaffold.don't get confused by the name bootomSheet. It always visible at th bottom of your screen

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: YourAppBar()
    body:YourChid(),
    bottomSheet: const PurchasingPlanSheet(),
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

To implement such view i recommend using **Slivers**.

**benefits**:

1. Sticky header/Footer.
2. infinity body/content scroll.

check the **code** below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Header',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, letterSpacing:4),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Center(child: Text('$index')),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            hasScrollBody: false,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Footer',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, letterSpacing: 4),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For more detail take a look here:

https://itnext.io/create-a-header-footer-with-scrollable-body-view-in-flutter-5551087270de

Comment: not sure if this is just me but it is not scrollable

Comment: can you share some code ?also check this example  https://github.com/obadajasm/Header-Body-Footer-example/blob/master/lib/home_page.dart

Comment: OMG! Thank you soo much!!