# How to create Header/Footer/Main layout in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm Working on creating the attached layout in Flutter. While I create something that works it is really complicated and ugly (code-wise). I would like suggestions on how to create it?

NOTE: I only wish to create it with standard layouts (Row/Column/Center/ etc..) I don't wish to use widgets like BottomNavigationBar.

[image]

Comment: Not even an AppBar? If that's the case you can just a normal column with the middle item wrapped with an Expanded.

Comment: Not even an AppBar. I'm learning what rows and columns can do for me :-)

Comment: maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65933844/4493817

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this, (pls read the commends in the code)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //You should use `Scaffold` if you have `TextField` in body.
      //Otherwise on focus your `TextField` won`t scroll when keyboard popup.
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            //Header Container
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              color: Colors.blue,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("Header"),
            ),

            //Body Container
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      height: 200.0,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("Content 1"),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      height: 300.0,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("Content 1"),
                    ),
                    //TextField nearly at bottom
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter Text Here"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            //Footer Container
            //Here you will get unexpected behaviour when keyboard pops-up. 
            //So its better to use `bottomNavigationBar` to avoid this.
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              color: Colors.blue,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("Footer"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @the footer is above the keyboard. So to avoid that I have added  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, this line of code. But that time it's not scrolling. Keep landscape also and notice. To get that TextFormField what we will do? I don't want the button above to the keyboard.

Comment: @SunishaSindhu as I mentioned in the comments of the above code, you should use the  `bottomNavigationBar` of the `Scaffold` widget.

Answer (score 1):

Try Column with three children, Header and Footer have a specific size and Content occupies the remaining of the space.

```
Column(
            children: [
              Container(height: 100, child: HeaderWidget),
              Expanded(child: ContentWidget),
              Container(height: 100, child: FooterWidget),
            ]
```

Scroll will be applied on the Content.

Comment: It's good when you are sure that your page is not scrollable. If it is scrollable, it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you don't want to use properties like AppBar or BottomNavigationBar. Why?
It helps you to solve the problem of difference if the page is scrollable or not or its questionable.

That is why the proper layout is:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: const SimpleAppBar(), // Your app bar
  body: _Body() // Your body,
  bottomSheet: const _Footer(), // Your footer
);
```